# How to edit the top right panels in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: panel, notification, notification-area

I want to be able to change the icons in the top right panel, by the time. 
I have tried Unity Tweak Tool, that only goes so far, and it doesn't cover third party icons at all.

I want to remove the En thing, I think its some sort of language selector or something similar, also I want to remove the Mail icon. It was Thunderbird Mail, I removed it, now it's Facebook messanger.

[image: Screenshot of notification bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this code in Terminal,

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages
```

**It should look like this in the terminal**

[image]

[image]

**And this when its complete**

**For this to take effect, you need to restart your computer,I hope this helped!**

Comment: Thanks John, that fixed the mail icon problem, but I would also like to remove the 'En' icon, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For the En, which I now know is text entry, I opened system settings, text entry and cleared the check-box labeled *show current input source in the menu bar*

For the mail thing, John hit the nail on the head for that one.

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/remove-keyboard-indicator-ubuntu/

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution!